# Sprite-Kit: Staying Inside Borders Created with Tile Editor

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skscene

[image]

I'm testing the possibility of the **tile editor** that comes with Xcode 8 (8.2.2).  And I've created a **PacMan**-like map as shown above.  There's a game character at the top-left corner in a rectangle.  I wonder if there's an easy way of making the game character staying inside the blue borders?  So far, I've set a (red) wall to the left like the following through the scene editor.  And I have the following lines of code.

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None:    UInt32 = 0
    static let Player:  UInt32 = 0b1 // 1
    static let Edge:    UInt32 = 0b10 // 2
    static let Wall:    UInt32 = 0b100 // 4
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var background: SKTileMapNode! // background
    var player: SKNode! // player

    // MARK: - DidMove
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        setupNodes()
    }

    func setupNodes() {
        background = self.childNode(withName: "World") as! SKTileMapNode
        background.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: background.frame)
        background.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge

        let wall = self.childNode(withName: "Wall")
        wall?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (wall?.frame.size)!)
        wall?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        wall?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Wall

        player = self.childNode(withName: "Player")
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 32)
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 4
        player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    }
}
```

The user will get to control the player position with `CoreMotion`.  For now, the game character does respect the left edge.  But if the map gets complicated, I could end up placing a lot of walls here and there.  And that kind of kills the fun as it could be time-consuming.  So, again, is there a simplier way of making the game character collide the map borders?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GameplayKit's pathfinding classes, specifically GKGridGraph and GKGridGraphNode which allow you to specify a graph that only has these kind of rectilinear paths.

There is a good tutorial from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html

And a demo app here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Pathfinder_GameplayKit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016461

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like a helpful tip.  I don't know how to actually apply the pathfinding thing to SKTileMapNode.  Apple's Pathfinder project doesn't use SKTileMapNode.